# Django partial update without form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django to write an app which is going to have an interface for automated requests and the like, which will not use a graphical/HTML UI. As of right now, I'm using a `ModelForm` to allow requests such as

```
POST /addFoo?a=1&b=Hello
```

which will create a new `Foo` with those fields and values and add it to the database. The view function looks like

```
def addFoo(request):
    form = FooForm(request)
    if form.is_valid():
        foo = form.save()
        return succeed(id=foo.id)
    else:
        return fail(code=0, error=form.errors)
```

where `succeed` and `fail` are functions to generate proper responses/log entries. This part works fine. However, I would like to write a similar function `editFoo` so that if there is an object with ID 1, then

```
POST /editFoo?id=1&a=42
```

will change that object's `a` field to 42. The view function as I currently have it is

```
def editFoo(request):
    try:
        foo = models.Foo.objects.get(id=request['id'])
    except:
        return fail(0, error=u'No such object exists!')
    form = FooForm(request, instance=foo)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return succeed()
    else:
        return fail(code=1, error=form.errors)
```

However, when I test this form.errors contains error messages to the effect that the unspecified fields are required. Since the initiation of these requests will be by the client (that is, I cannot pre-load an HTML `<form>` for them to edit), I can't seem to find a way to make this sort of view work.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

EDIT: Model and Form are really simple:

```
class Foo(Model):
    a = IntegerField()
    b = CharField(max_length=23)
```

and

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

Comment: write the model and modelform code, please

Comment: Not much going on, but added.

Comment: For creation, yes. But, for example, I would issue the following requests:

    `POST /addFoo?a=13&b=Hello`

which returns `id=1`, and then

    `POST /editFoo?id=1&a=42`

which fails.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the "csrf_token"? write the error log

Comment: It's not `csrf_token`, since I disabled the middleware.

Comment: `form.errors` is `{"b": ["This field is required."]}`.

Comment: Quick warning: be careful when creating interfaces like these. It's very easy to create security vulnerabilities, where users can change fields that they shouldn't. For example, [github had an exploit in 2012](https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation) (they use ruby, not python, but the principle is the same).

Comment: I'm hoping this should be secure since the actual implementation checks permissions for the request.user object. Permissions are granted per-instance so there is no "some fields should be changed; some not" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a form class that contains only the fields that you're expecting to get from your POST, or that allows the fields to be omitted even though they are required on the model itself.

Limiting the fields present:

```
class FooEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('a',)
```

Allowing the fields to be omitted:

```
class FooEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    a = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    b = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=23)
```

Or edit them in the form's `__init__` method:

```
class FooEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.itervalues():
            field.required = False
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what fields I'm expecting until I get them, since the client can choose to change any of the fields. I don't think `modelform_factory` for each request is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: In that case, make the fields not required in the form by explicitly declaring them and therefore overriding the default fields.  I'll edit to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you, that last one is exactly what I was looking for! I considered the second but it seemed to be a terrible violation of DRY (on top of which some of these models are rather complicated). Will try it out and accept.

Comment: That's a pretty common idiom when you want to change only a little bit about a model form's behavior.  Depending on how far you're going with creating and updating your objects you might want to look into some of the existing REST packages rather than writing the views - I've had good results with piston in the past, but it's not the only one.  https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home

Comment: Ah, slight edit to your post: `self.fields` is a dict so it has to be `self.fields.itervalues()`. Otherwise it seems good!

Comment: Be careful setting `required=False` for fields, there's a gotcha: If you make a char field `a` optional, and the user only submits a new value for `b`, then Django will overwrite `a` with the empty string `''`.

Comment: Good point there.  Hmm.  Maybe it's best not to use the form's `save()` method at all.  You can still use them for validation, but after checking `is_valid` loop through the keys that are in both `request.POST` and `form.cleaned_data` and set the model attributes from that set with the values from `cleaned_data`.

Comment: Okay, so I wound up doing it differently after all, with respect to @Alasdair's comment, which was perfectly correct. I wound up binding the form with `FooForm(model_to_dict(foo).update(request), instance=foo)` which is kinda clunky but seems to work. Thank you both for your help.